# Jenkins Build Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/sqljet/core/table/SqlJetTimeoutBusyHandler

Tags: java, jenkins, svn

**Error Log:**

```
Started by user jenkins
Building in workspace /www/dev/apps/jenkins/workspace/app_11001
FATAL: org/tmatesoft/sqljet/core/table/SqlJetTimeoutBusyHandler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/sqljet/core/table/SqlJetTimeoutBusyHandler
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.db.SVNSqlJetDb.<clinit>(SVNSqlJetDb.java:49)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.openDb(SVNWCDb.java:4775)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.parseDir(SVNWCDb.java:1849)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.detectWcGeneration(SvnOperationFactory.java:1555)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.getImplementation(SvnOperationFactory.java:1219)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1138)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2485)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.parseSvnInfo(UpdateUpdater.java:126)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.getSvnCommandToUse(UpdateUpdater.java:88)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:131)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:977)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:953)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:902)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:838)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetTimeoutBusyHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've also added **sqljet.jar** file in my /lib folder but that doesn't helped me. when I click on build and within some sort of time I am getting same error and build failed.

I am using Apache Tomcat 8 for Jenkins.

Comment: It shall be placed under `Full path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @Optional It is already there under path as below.
jenkins/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/sqljet-1.1.6-sources.jar

Comment: Hey @JigneshSavaliya, what does it mean by "app_11001" ? 11001 confused here.

Comment: @vishalgajera app_11001 is Job name defined in Jenkins Job.